# can't read from txt file python

Tags: python

```
def add(num1,num2):
    print(num1+num2)


try:
    filename = input()
    f = open(filename,"r")
    readFile = f.readlines()
    f.close()
    for line in readFile:
        exec(line)

except FileNotFoundError:
    print("Failed to open",filename)
```

I have a function called add() given a text file with values like this add(12345667890123456789,8765432109876543210). I need to open text file then execute that function. Why doesn't the code above open the file?

Comment: Try placing the file in a different location. The Admin folder may be protected.

Comment: You are calling ```input``` which means that ```filename``` will be whatever you type in the console, not the path you pass to it. Remove the ```input```

Comment: Also, you should look at the ```with``` statement

Comment: Once you get past the file-opening issue, you're going to have another issue until you add code to parse `line in readFile` into `num1` and `num2`

Comment: I don't know if it's a typo but you pass one argument in add functions and you need two. Also, explain better what do you want to implement. Because, the reading process it look's ok, but the add function in the loop is strange. You have num1 and num2, but you are not assign any value in this code

Comment: @NathanHawks you are in my mind :-)

Comment: You can iterate over a file object directly to get lines, no need for `.readlines()`. Also, variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Comment: Another issue at hand may be that the `input()` was intentional and just used wrong. To provide default value to an `input()` you actually do something like the following, after the `input()` call: `defaultFilename = (your default filename)` and then `filename = filename if filename else defaultFilename`

Comment: so, I need to open the file in linux, by typing python3 infint.py "input=<file name>" (infint.py is my source code name), but i don't know how to fix it.

Comment: @BayramJumageldiyev That's another matter entirely, no?

Comment: thank you everyone, i fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
with open("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\tc6.txt", 'r') as f:
    readFile = f.readlines()
```